# Preguntas consideradas que no tienen el suficiente nivel o de baja calidad para estar en StackOverflow

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, preguntas

Sobre las preguntas, las que son mal realizadas, sin fundamento, sin lógica, o que el autor pretende que se le haga el trabajo, por lo general son llenadas a negativos, las que soy muy abiertas son cerradas y se le pide al autor que la edite y la realice mejor, las que no son en español pues se ponen en espera para que las traduzcan, esa es la mecánica que se lleva.

Pero paso a preguntarme, ¿esas que se consideran que son de baja calidad y que afectan a la página, con qué regla lo miden, qué criterios se utiliza para que cualquier usuario pueda determinar que cierta pregunta es de baja calidad?

Por los votos negativos lo dudo, hay preguntas que son tachadas de bajo calidad, pero que no poseen ni un solo voto negativo, con 2 o 3 respuestas, pero a su vez no poseen ni un sólo voto positivo, o sea que se podría tachar de mala calidad a las que tenga 0 votos.

Es muy subjetivo porque una persona con un nivel de experiencia alto en un tema determinado, cierta pregunta le va a parecer de bajo nivel, contrario a una persona que empieza en ese tema, la misma pregunta puede llegarle a ser complicada.

Otra cosa que pienso es que una pregunta sencilla no siempre se puede tachar de no tener el nivel suficiente, varia mucho de persona en persona, y de pendiendo de su nivel de conocimiento en el tema en particular. Claro y es fácil identificarlo cuando se lee desde el otro lado.

Ahora si eres tú el que realiza la pregunta, en un tema poco machacado por tí, ¿cómo puedes identificar que esa pregunta que vas a realizar es de mala calidad cuando no se posee la experiencia ni el conocimiento para determinarlo?

¿Bajo qué se fundamenta que una pregunta es de bajo nivel, que reglas o qué estándares hay, qué reglas se pueden seguir para que varias personas con diferentes grados de conocimiento y diferentes pensamiento lleguen a la misma conclusión y no caer en subjetividad?.

Answer (score 4):

La referencia básica para determinar si una pregunta es de baja calidad es el artículo de ayuda

[¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Como verás el enfoque es positivo, en lugar de decir "baja calidad" dice "buena pregunta".

En resumen, una buena pregunta

1. Es clara
2. Incluye una breve descripción de lo buscado/investigado
3. Es útil tanto para el que pregunta como también para los otros
4. La utilidad de la pregunta perdurará por un período extenso de tiempo.

Cabe destacar que las preguntas deben ser dentro de la temática del sitio y que no es indispensable que se incluya código pero en muchos casos el código resulta útil para hacer la pregunta clara y mostrar los que se ha intentado como resultado de la búsqueda e investigación realizadas.

Otras características importantes son que la pregunta

- sea concreta, es decir que no sea demasiado amplia
- pueda tener una respuesta objetiva es decir no ser una pregunta "principalmente basada en opiniones".